# Can I move Zelda Breath of the Wild data to a new Wii U?

Tags: wii-u, zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I played Zelda Breath of the Wild on my friend's Wii U. However, I have recently bought myself a Wii U and a copy of the game. Is there a way to transfer data over to my Wii U? I used my own profile when playing the game.
Thanks!

Comment: Haven't tested this, so I'm not posting it as an answer, but can't you stick a USB drive into your friend's Wii U, move the save data onto it, then plug the drive into your own Wii U and play off of it? You might need to extract the save data from it into the game data from your purchased copy.

Comment: No, you can't. The USB drive is formatted for an unique wiiu. The pendrive would be usable only on his friend's console.

Answer (score 6):

Sadly it is not possible to move saved data from one Wii U console to another one there are several articles on this on Nintendo's support site. All detail the same answer. This particular one breaks it down in a pretty simple way.

https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/social/questions/detail/qid/47117/~/any-possible-way-of-moving%2Ftransferring-wii-u-save-files-to-another-system